# subprocess.Popen Redirect stdout to a file without blocking

Tags: python

We can redirect the stdout to a file as

```
with open('/tmp/test.log', 'w') as fp:
   p = subprocess.Popen(['exe'], stdout=fp)
```

The subprocess will run for an hour or so.
My understanding is we need to wait for the subprocess to close inside the `with` block so that `fp` is always valid.

But the test cases I ran were working fine without having a blocking wait.

If it is a good practice to actually wait, is there any other way to get this done without blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Better use

```
fp = open(...
```

instead of.

```
with open (...
```